# Raspberry pi zero not connecting to TV

Tags: raspbian

I have just got a Raspberry Pi Zero. I plugged into the TV using HDMI output but no signal. OS already installed on the SD card.

Comment: Welcome to RaspberryPi.StackExchange! Could you elaborate a bit on your setup? What cable did you use to connect? What source is the TV on? How are you powering the Pi? What are the specs of the power supply you use? How did you install Raspbian? Are there any lights on on the Pi and if yes, which ones and are they on solid or flashing? That way we're not guessing as to your setup.

Comment: Hey man thanks  , power supply came with it , basically I bought the whole kit from pimoroni. I used hdmi cable which I use for sky box and TV is on hdmi source , I even tried it with my PC screen using same hdmi connection but still no result , the kit came with 8GB pre installed OS , and yes green light is blinking , it flashes for few seconds then stay solid for like 2 seconds and goes back to flashing

Comment: Is that *erratic flashing*, or is it in a regular rhythm like 5 quick flashes, pause, 5 quick flashes again?  The latter will be very obvious so do not overthink it.  The former is normal.

Comment: Yes that's right it's in regular rhythm of 5 flashes and pause for few seconds

Comment: @Waqas: That means that `start.elf` is not found.  I would try reinstalling the OS.

Answer (score 2):

According to [elinux's documentation](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern), 5 flashes and a pause from the green LED indicates that `start.elf` is not found. I would try reinstalling the OS.